# (Scala) Keeping the structure of a list in the output

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, nested-lists

I need a little assistance.

I've been working out the functional aspects in Scala. Almost all the work is in lists and for the most part, I can work out the problems, but I hit a small dead-end. I can't keep the original form (structure) of the list in certain problems. In the output all the nested lists get flattened. Concatenate `:::` flattens the list(that is an element of the original list) and append `::` gives me a compilation error, as it requires a generic T type (not a list).

A very simple example, in which I want to remove the first element of a list that matches the input:

```
def removeFirst[T](obj: T, list: List[T]): List[T] = {
  if (list isEmpty) Nil
  else{
  val fin: List[T] = list.head match {
    case headAsList: List[T] => if (containsWithNestedLists(obj, headAsList))
      removeFirst(obj, headAsList) ::: list.tail
    else headAsList ::: removeFirst(obj, list.tail)
    case _ => if (list.head == obj) list.tail
    else if (list.tail == List()) List(list.head)
    else list.head :: removeFirst(obj, list.tail)
  }
  fin
  }
}
```

For one level deep lists, it works fine, but 
the output that comes out for
`removeFirst(1,List(List(1,2,3),1,2,3,4,5,6))`  is *List(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)*, where as ideally I would want *List(List(2,3),1,2,3,4,5,6))*.

Or the more specific input `removeFirst(1,List(List(2,3,List()),List(1,2,3),1,2,3,4,5,6,List(2,3,List())))`
should have output = `List(List(2,3,List()),List(2,3),1,2,3,4,5,6,List(1,2,3,List()))`

Also I have found that removing the generic `T` and using `Any` in its place does the trick, but I also know that `Any` is a big **no-no** and a temporary solution for a permanent problem, as in other functions it hasn't helped.

As far as I know, I haven't seen a helpful solution on the internet, so I have to ask. Am I missing something, need to debug or is there another function that could help me? The closest I've come to my answer is using append `::` in some manner, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide a few examples of what you're looking for in your function? 

Example: `double: Int => Int, double(5) === 10`

Comment: For this specific function I do have a version that works as I intend

    def removeFirst(obj: Any, list: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
      if (list isEmpty) Nil
      else {
      val fin: List[Any] = list.head match {
        case headAsList: List[Any] => if (containsWithNestedLists(obj, headAsList))
          removeFirst(obj, headAsList) :: list.tail
        else headAsList :: removeFirst(obj, list.tail)
        case _ => if (list.head == obj) list.tail
        else list.head :: removeFirst(obj, list.tail)
      }
      fin
      }
    }

If you test some examples, you'll probably get what..

Comment: For multi-line code in comments, I politely recommend using a [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: ..I intend as output, way better than I can explain.
But the main problem I was having was with keeping the structure intact (with generics, not `Any`). The function can be removing the last occurrence of an element, all occurrences, the N-th occurrence, removing all elements on the N-th level list, adding an element to the N-th level list, etc etc.
Edit: sorry about the code, I'm new at this :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b8a4331ce03d3ee180c
The code for the working function

Comment: @Nik.S. Hey man, just doing some cleanup. Is this question resolved?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yeah, the question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You examples just look as if you want to remove a certain element from the list if it is present.
For flat lists you can do this much simpler:

```
def removeFirst[T](obj: T, list: List[T]) = list match {
  case `obj` :: rest => rest
  case _ => list
}
```

This will do the following:

```
> removeFirst(1, List(1, List(1,2,3)))
res57: List[Any] = List(List(1, 2, 3))
> removeFirst(1, List(2, List(1,2,3)))
res58: List[Any] = List(2, List(1, 2, 3))
> removeFirst(List(2,3), List(List(2,3), List(1,2,3)))
res59: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3))
```

However, it seems you want to do this for arbitrarily nested Lists. This is not directly possible, as Scala cannot express the exact type of that. The type you'd need would be something like

```
type NestedList[T] = List[T union NestedList[T]]
```

Scala does not have union types and you cannot do recursive definitions in this way, so you can not just do this either:

```
type NestedList[T] = List[Either[T, NestedList[T]]]
```

You can however do it, if you use a class instead of a type:

```
case class NestedList[T](value: List[Either[T, NestedList[T]]])
```

Now you can write your algorithm like this:

```
def removeFirst[T](obj: T, list: NestedList[T]): NestedList[T] = {
  val rest = list.value match {
    case Left(`obj`) :: tail => tail
    case __ => list.value
  }
  NestedList(rest.map {
    case Right(r) => Right(removeFirst(obj, r))
    case Left(r) => Left(r)
  })
}
```

And you can do this:

```
> removeFirst(1, NestedList(List(Left(1), Left(2),  Right(NestedList(List(Left(1),Left(3)))))))
res71: NestedList[Int] = NestedList(List(Left(2), Right(NestedList(List(Left(3))))))
```

It is of course a bit cumbersome to build and decompose these structures. So maybe it would be better to build a proper tree class using a sealed abstract class and two case classes instead of using the Either.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, basically this can't be done in a purely functional way (it needs classes), but I have to admit, it seems way too complex and inelegant for something very easily done in other functional languages.

Comment: Which functional languages are you referring to? I chose not to try to make this cleaner because I didn't want to define my own tree type, but i could have easily done that. This won't be much different in any other functional languages that does not allow recursive type definitions as the one above. And you are also mistaken: this is purely functional code. The class I've used here is just a simple data type.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I mixed up what I meant to say. What I meant was, it (probably) can't be done purely with the `List` data type that is given by Scala, and requires changes in the type, not the function. As to which functional languages, primarily I would say Common Lisp (in which this kind of manipulation with lists is the easiest), but I have also been able to do this kind of problems in Prolog (not really a functional programming language) and Haskell.

Comment: Well, lisp is not statically typed. You can have that in Scala with Any. And in Haskell I would expect it to be pretty similar, you would define a recursive data type for it, would you not? If you would define it by just nesting Either you would get pretty much the same thing in Haskell. Anyway, I can't really see how this is a common problem. If it were, there would be a nested list data type out there. It is easy enough to build.

Comment: True on all accounts. The problem wasn't building the new data type, I just thought it was possible to do this sort of problems with the basic `List` data type in Scala and generics, but I guess it has to be with done with Any. Thank you for the help.